# Pass the Material UI Tab heading as a URL parameter React

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I want to pass the selected date as a parameter when the showtime button is clicked. I couldn't find a way and I'm new to React. looking for suggestions.

Following is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState }from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import PhoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Phone";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import PersonPinIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PersonPin";
import HelpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Help";
import ShoppingBasket from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingBasket";
import ThumbDown from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbDown";
import ThumbUp from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { DateRangeSharp } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { List, ListItem, ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

    
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-force-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};


function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-force-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
}));


export default function ScrollableTabsButtonForce() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue ] = React.useState(0);
  const [venuesDates, setvenuesDates] = React.useState([]);
  const [showtimesData] = React.useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "http://sandbox-api.tickets.lk/v1/movie/3232/showtime";
    const requestOptions = (token) => {
      return ({
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
      })
    };
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions());
        const json = await response.json();
        // console.log(json);
        // console.log(json.data.venueDateShowtime)
        setvenuesDates(json.data.venueDateShowtime);
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log("error",error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();

  })

  const search = useLocation().search;
  const Mid = new URLSearchParams(search).get('movieid');
  const Mname = new URLSearchParams(search).get('name');
  // console.log(Mname)



  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };




  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar
        position="static"
        style={{ background: "#333545", minHeight: 60 }}
      >
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="on"
          indicatorColor="secondary"
          textColor="primary"
          aria-label="scrollable force tabs example"
          style={{ minHeight: 60 }}
          wrapped
        >
          {venuesDates.map((showtdates) => {
            return (
              <Tab
                label={showtdates.date}
                {...a11yProps(0)}
                style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 20, minHeight: 60 }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {/* map over dates and create TabPanel */}
{/* // check if theater property exists and create a list of theaters as an example */}
{venuesDates.map((date, idx) => {
        
        const venues = date.hasOwnProperty("venues")
          ? date.venues.map((venues) => (
              <ListItem>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={venues.venue}
                  secondary={venues.venueId}
                />
                {date.venues.map((date)=> {
                  const showtimes = venues.hasOwnProperty("showtimes")
                  ? venues.showtimes.map((showtimes) => (
                      // <ListItemText primary={showtimes.showtime} />                     
                        <Link to={'/seat-booking?movieid=' + Mid +"&name=" + Mname + "&theater=" + venues.venueId +
                         "&movieDate=" + "showtdates.date" +  "&showtimes=" + showtimes.showtimeId} 
                        style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}>
                          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{margin:5}}>
                        {showtimes.showtime}
                        </Button>
                        </Link>
                  ))
                  :null;
                  return(
                    <List>{showtimes}</List>
                  )
                })}
                   
              </ListItem>
            ))
            : null;
        return (
          <TabPanel value={value} index={idx}>
            <List>{venues}</List>
          </TabPanel>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I really want to get the selected date from the Tab heading and pass as a parameter as mentioned below.
I need to change the "&movieDate=" + "showtdates.date" ===> as "&movieDate=" + (selected tab heading name)

```
            {date.venues.map((date)=> {
              const showtimes = venues.hasOwnProperty("showtimes")
              ? venues.showtimes.map((showtimes) => (
                  // <ListItemText primary={showtimes.showtime} />                     
                    <Link to={'/seat-booking?movieid=' + Mid +"&name=" + Mname + "&theater=" + venues.venueId +
                     "&movieDate=" + "showtdates.date" +  "&showtimes=" + showtimes.showtimeId} 
                    style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}>
                      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{margin:5}}>
                    {showtimes.showtime}
                    </Button>
                    </Link>
              ))
              :null;
              return(
                <List>{showtimes}</List>
              )
            })}
```